# Theme drop down missing in Stors > Config > Design

Tags: magento2, theme

I have added a custom theme under app/design/frontend

The theme, along with blank and luma are visible under Content > Themes

However when going to Stores > Config > General and selection the Design tab there are no design related options visible. Only a single entry related to search. It's like all design options including theme selection have been removed.

Do I need to do something else to makes design options visible?

Comment: Can you please share the your theme.xml and registration.php along with file path ?

Answer (score 1):

Try under content ->design->configuration .you can find there.